# Disable tabstops with CSS?

Tags: css

Google is telling me no but most answers are "don't disable tabstops" or telling end users to use the tabindex property, so figured I'd ask...

Being able to disable tabstops with CSS would really simplify a solution I'm working on.  Any nifty tricks out there?  I don't want to remove anything from the document flow - just obscure them from the keyboard, as they're already obscured from mouse-interactions (specifically I'm working on our modal dialogs).  They may or may not be visible in the background.

I have a JS solution already - just seeing if there's a pure CSS way to do it.

Clarifications:
*tabindex -1 is what the existing JS solution is doing.  Just seeing if there's a way to do this via CSS, as CSS solutions are always preferable when possible.
*It's an accessibility improvement to remove obscured items from the tabindex - like when you open the save as... dialog in word, and it keeps tabs from wandering across all the other menus, keeping you in what you specifically opened.  The modals are to facilitate the page's use, not something like an unprompted ad.

Comment: To get meaningful direction, I think you'll need to include some code as a [mcve].  Also, I'm suspicious that this might be an XY problem-- I'm concerned that you're committing some accessibility antipatterns in what you are doing, and would need to see an example to really understand what it is you are trying to accomplish and and explanation as to _why_.

Comment: Sorry - it's a modal dialog, it's easy to close (escape key closes it and there's a button at the top of its read order to close it), and marked w/ the appropriate role.  Contents in our modals are typically things that'd clutter the page but are still related (like a contact form on a page that lists several different ways to contact us).  When the modal is open, the page is obscured by the modal.  It getting keyboard focus is a bad experience for keyboard users, as they can't necessarily see what has focus.  When they reach the end of the dialog, it goes back to close.

Comment: And tabindex=-1 is what the JS solution is setting now - just seeing if there's a pure css way to do it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  For what its worth, the [WAI authoring example for a modal](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html) describes actually _trapping_ focus in the modal, so when `tab` his keyed when on the last focusable element in the modal the next item focused is the _first_ focusable element in the modal.  The link above contains a JS solution for this.  This is a little bit different than your current approach, which makes other focusable elements non-focusable but doesn't _trap_ focus.  Good luck, and happy coding!